# Ev3 mindstorm going back and forward in a straight line

Tags: lego-mindstorms

I want to write a code for my Ev3 robot with two motors. I want it to be able to go a certain distance, in this case forward until the motors have turned a maximum of 2500 degress for four seconds. Then I want the robot to go back the same distance. But the problem is that sometimes only one motor spins while the other does nothing and sometimes a motor will continue to spin long after it has returned to its original position. I wonder if there is any way I can improve the code I have. I have tried it on several different Ev3 equitment so it is most likely not a hardware problem. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
b = Brick('ioType','usb');
b.outputStepSpeed(0,Device.MotorA,60,0,2500,0,Device.Brake);
b.outputStepSpeed(0,Device.MotorD,60,0,2500,0,Device.Brake); 
pause(4) 
b.outputStop(0,Device.MotorA,Device.Brake);
b.outputStop(0,Device.MotorD,Device.Brake); 
tacho = b.outputGetCount(0,Device.MotorA);         
disp(['> Tachometer: ' num2str(tacho)]);
b.outputClrCount(0,Device.MotorA); 
b.outputClrCount(0,Device.MotorD); 
pause(0) 
b.outputStepSpeed(0,Device.MotorA,-60,0,tacho,0,Device.Brake); 
b.outputStepSpeed(0,Device.MotorD,-60,0,tacho,0,Device.Brake); 
pause(4) 
b.outputStop(0,Device.MotorA,Device.Brake); 
b.outputStop(0,Device.MotorD,Device.Brake); 
tacho = 
b.outputGetCount(0,Device.MotorA);         
disp(['> Tachometer: ' num2str(tacho)]); 
b.outputClrCount(0,Device.MotorA); 
b.outputClrCount(0,Device.MotorD); 
clear
```

Answer (score 0):

do check if your ports are correct and if they are connected. Do also know that not all EV3 motors are manufactured perfectly the same which means some can be stronger, making it almost impossible to move straight. Using a gyro might help out in this case.

Do comment if you need further help!